# show/hide series vanishes styling of datalable

Tags: highcharts

In my chart I am combining a class together with datalables of each series.
At some point I am hiding datalables of one series. But If now I show/hide any other series, the hided datalables appears.

I made a jsfiddle example. Do the following steps to see my meaning:
1. click on button 1 to hide datalables on series1
2. Hide series 2

Now the datalables on series 1 shows up. How can I stop this behavior?

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jmogexfj/2/

```
$(function () {

button1();

$('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                 useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<div class="label_'+this.series._i+'">' + this.y + '</div>';
                    }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    },
                {
        data: [10.9, 50.5, 60.4, 100.2, 104.0, 106.0, 120.6, 108.5, 106.4, 104.1, 90.6, 50.4]
    }]
});
});


 function button1(){
   $("#b1").click(function(){
    $(".label_0").toggle();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how Highcharts library works. When you update chart (like hiding by legend, resizing window browser etc.), elements are redrawn.

To hide dataLabels, use `series.update()`:

```
    $('#container').highcharts().series[0].update({
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false   
        }
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jmogexfj/4/

If you really need to use classes, then use [`chart.events.redraw`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) to show/hide dataLabel on each redraw: http://jsfiddle.net/jmogexfj/5/

Highcharts example:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            redraw: function () {
                var showOrHide = display ? 'show' : 'hide';
                $(".label_0")[showOrHide]();
            }
        }
    },
```

Click button:

```
function button1() {
  $("#b1").click(function () {
    display = !display;
    $(".label_0").toggle();
  });
}
```